# Problem with manually allocating memory address for a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to work with flash memory on MPC5748G - a microcontroller from NXP running FreeRTOS 10.0.1, and I get some behaviour that I can't understand.

I am allocating memory manually, and the assignment seems not to work. However, I can reach the value at the address when using 'printf' - but only from the same function.
(I'm using the copy of a pointer, to make sure that some sore of compiler optimisation doesn't take place)

```
void vFlashTask(void* pvParameters){
   vTaskDelay(1000);
   FLASH_DRV_Init();
   uint32_t* val_ptr; 
   uint32_t* val_ptr_cpy;
   val_ptr = (uint32_t *)0xFB8000;
   val_ptr_cpy = val_ptr;
   
   *val_ptr = 444;

   DBGPRINTF("Task| value at xFB8000:%d", *val_ptr_cpy);
   
   getValTest();
   vTaskDelay(1500);
   vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

void getValTest(){
   uint32_t* val_ptr;
   val_ptr =(uint32_t *)0xfb8000;
   DBGPRINTF("getValTest| value at xFB8000:%d", *val_ptr);
}
```

Gives back (in UART Terminal):

```
   [../include/flash.c:26]: Task| value at xFB8000:444
   [../include/flash.c:37]: getValTest| value at xFB8000:-1
```

I am attaching also the screenshot from the debugger, which clearly shows that however memory at the xFB8000 is uninitialized (it has the value of 0xffffffff), but still, the printf function manages to print the correct value(?).

[image: debugger ouptut]

My DBGPRINTF macro:

```
#define DBGPRINTF(f, ...)           dbgPrintf("[%s:%d]: " f "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)

void dbgPrintf(const char *format, ...){
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int len = vsnprintf((char*) uart_buffer, UART_BUFFER_SIZE - 1, format,  args);
    UART_SendDataBlocking(&uart_pal1_instance, (const char *)uart_buffer, len, UART_TIMEOUT);
    va_end(args);
 }
```

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions.

My compiler flags:

```
\S32DS_Power_v2.1\eclipse\../S32DS/software/S32_SDK_S32PA_RTM_3.0.3/rtos/FreeRTOS_PA/Source/portable/GCC/PowerPC" -I"C:\NXP\S32DS_Power_v2.1\eclipse\../S32DS/software/S32_SDK_S32PA_RTM_3.0.3/middleware/tcpip/tcpip_stack/ports/OS" -I"C:\NXP\S32DS_Power_v2.1\eclipse\../S32DS/software/S32_SDK_S32PA_RTM_3.0.3/middleware/tcpip/tcpip_stack/ports/platform/generic/gcc/setting" -I"C:\NXP\S32DS_Power_v2.1\eclipse\../S32DS/software/S32_SDK_S32PA_RTM_3.0.3/middleware/tcpip/wolfssl/wolfssl" -I"C:\NXP\S32DS_Power_v2.1\eclipse\../S32DS/software/S32_SDK_S32PA_RTM_3.0.3/middleware/tcpip/wolfssl" -I"C:\NXP\S32DS_Power_v2.1\eclipse\../S32DS/software/S32_SDK_S32PA_RTM_3.0.3/rtos/FreeRTOS_PA/Source" -I"C:\NXP\S32DS_Power_v2.1\eclipse\../S32DS/software/S32_SDK_S32PA_RTM_3.0.3/platform/pal/inc" -I"C:\NXP\S32DS_Power_v2.1\eclipse\../S32DS/software/S32_SDK_S32PA_RTM_3.0.3/platform/drivers/src/flash_c55" -O1 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -msdata=eabi -mlra -funsigned-bitfields -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-common -Wno-address -mcpu=e200z4 -specs=nosys.specs -mbig -mvle -mregnames -mhard-float --sysroot="C:\NXP\S32DS_Power_v2.1\eclipse\../S32DS/build_tools/powerpc-eabivle-4_9/powerpc-eabivle/newlib"
```

Comment: its normal ram at that address? Its not some memory mapped controller thing?

Comment: It's supposed to be flash.
I tried the same code with RAM, and the results were similar.

Comment: thats plain weird. I assume its not compiler optimization since this seems to be a debug build and that normally suppresses compiler cleverness. I would step into the printf function to see when it gets 444 and from where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was writing to FLASH memory - it hasn't been correctly  initialized.

The proper way to write to flash on MPC5748g using the SDK 3.0.3 is following:

- save flash controller cache
- initialise flash
- check and protect UT block
- unblock an address space
- erase a block in this space
- check if the space block is blank
- program the block
- verify if the block is programmed correctly
- check sum of the programmed data
- restore flash controller cache

The strange behaviour of printf and pointer was due to compiler optimization. After changing the compiler flags to -O0 (no optimization), the error was consistent.

The same consistent error can be achieved when marking the pointers as 'volatile'.